# Trilateration question help

Tags: circles

Kind of stuck n this question, I just got the circle equation written down for the robot don't know what to do from here.

A bicycle robot is travelling on a circle centred at the origin and with a radius of 6m. The
robot measures its position by sending signals to another turtle robot travelling on the
straight line y = x and looking for reflected signals. The bicycle robot comes to a stop and
measures its distance from the turtle robot to be 6 root 2 m at a point when the path of the
latter intersects with that of the former. Calculate the location of the bicycle robot.

Comment: Your robot is (1) on the circle $R=6$ and (2) given distance from the described point. From (1) you have one circle's equation, from (2) derive another circle's equation (because a known distance from a fixed point defines a circle). Then solve the system of two equations to find an intersection of the circles.